# Any way to limit the execution runs in a logic app?

Tags: limit, azure-logic-apps

Hi Is there any way to limit the execution runs in a logic app from multiple instances to one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at concurrency control as seen in this excellent post: https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/logic-apps-concurrency-control/

This is the way to implement it, in code view:

```
"runtimeConfiguration": {
      "concurrency" : {
         "runs": 2
      }
   },
```

Comment: I just notised i have 2 of those. i think they are related to my "foreach" loops. Also my trigger is a : "When_a_file_is_added_or_modified" SFTP...

Comment: @John please post your Logic App definition because the details you are adding now invalidate the answer which is perfectly correct. It's not easy to guess what your setup is and what exactly do you want to limit to one-at-a-time run model.

Comment: i've got a servicebus trigger that's triggered the execution of my logic app. when limiting concurrency to 2 with the `runtimeconfiguration` as you suggest in your answer, this doesnt seem to be taking into effect at all. furthermore, when i look at the logic app in the portal in the settings of the first action the servicebus trigger, it shows that's just configured for the maximum. what am i doing wrong?